# How to replace values in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning how to implement and evaluate a Logistic Regression Model, for this I need to change the values of my array from strings to 0 & 1.

I have the following numpy ndarray as a result of a `DataFrame.values` call
`['PAIDOFF', 'COLLECTION', 'COLLECTION', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', 'PAIDOFF', ...]`
I would like to know how can I change the values like:
`'PAIDOFF' to 0` and `'COLLECTION' to 1`

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(['PAIDOFF', 'COLLECTION', 'COLLECTION', 'PAIDOFF'])

f = lambda x: 1 if x == "COLLECTION" else 0

np.fromiter(map(f,a),dtype=np.int)
```

Alternative:

```
np.where(a == "COLLECTION",1,0)
```

Comment: So simple, thank you very much!